# Invalid expression term error in the code below

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Error is in Create() function

- Create()
- Error    1   'MvcAnketaIT.Controllers.SurveyController.Create()': not all code paths return a value

Code

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        int myId = getIdByUser(this.User.Identity.Name);
        if (this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {

            if (myId == -1) //no questionnaire in db           
            {
                     SurveyModel survey = new SurveyModel();
                     ViewBag.userName = this.User.Identity.Name;
                     ViewBag.Q3Sex = new SelectList(db.Genders, "ID", "gender");
                     ViewBag.Q8Question1 = new SelectList(db.Questions1, "Id", "Technology");
                     ViewBag.Q9Question2_1 = new SelectList(db.Satisfaction, "ID", "Name");
                     ViewBag.Q10Question2_2 = new SelectList(db.Satisfaction, "ID", "Name");
                     ViewBag.Q11Question2_3 = new SelectList(db.Satisfaction, "ID", "Name");
                     ViewBag.Q12Question2_4 = new SelectList(db.Satisfaction, "ID", "Name");
                     ViewBag.Q13Question2_5 = new SelectList(db.Satisfaction, "ID", "Name");
                     ViewBag.Q14Question2_6 = new SelectList(db.Satisfaction, "ID", "Name");
                     ViewBag.Q15Question2_7 = new SelectList(db.Satisfaction, "ID", "Name");
                     ViewBag.Q16Question2_8 = new SelectList(db.Satisfaction, "ID", "Name");
                     ViewBag.Q17Question3 = new SelectList(db.Questions3, "ID", "Solve");
                     ViewBag.Q19Question5 = new SelectList(db.Questions5, "ID", "No_Contacts");
                     ViewBag.Q20Question6 = new SelectList(db.Questions6, "ID", "Recommendation");
                     return View();

            }
        }

         else //user already has a questionnaire fulfilled
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Edit/" + myId); //redirect to the right id of the user
            }
    }
```

Comment: You do understand that all code paths should return a value, right?

Comment: So then why not just add a line to return a view outside of the main if?  That'll fix it easily.

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring a variable inside of an `if` block:

```
if (something)
{
    int myId = getIdByUser(this.User.Identity.Name);
}
else
{
    // myId doesn't exist here.
}
```

So that variable is only accessible within the scope of that block.  To use it in a larger scope, it needs to be declared outside of the block:

```
int myId;
if (something)
{
    myId = getIdByUser(this.User.Identity.Name);
}
else
{
    // myId is accessible here
    // though runs the risk of not having been set to anything
    // depending on whether or not the if condition was met
}
```

**Edit:** What you've added to your question is a completely different issue.  The message is clear, though.  Not all code paths return a value.  The structure of what you have can be simplified to this:

```
if (something)
{
    if (something_else)
    {
        return;
    }
}
else
{
    return;
}
```

What will happen if `something` is true, but `something_else` is not?  No `return` statement is ever reached.  Thus, nothing is returned from the function.  This results in a compiler error.  You need to return something from the function in every code path.  In this case, here:

```
if (something)
{
    if (something_else)
    {
        return;
    }
    // Need to return a value here
}
else
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: @R.D: That's a completely different problem, but I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the scope of the variable - myID is declared in the IF block and you are trying to use it in the ELSE block.

The else block does not know about this variable, which is the error message you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

myId has to be defined outside of the if block as in the else, you haven't declared it.  Try this instead, version 2:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    int myId = getIdByUser(this.User.Identity.Name);
    if (this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        if (myId == -1) //no questionnaire in db           
        {
            SurveyModel survey = new SurveyModel();          
            return View();         
        }
    }   
    else //user already has a questionnaire fulfilled
    {
        //redirect to the right id of the user
        return RedirectToAction("Edit/" + myId); 
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: I was going to suggest that, but I wasn't sure if that would cause a null ref ex. (not sure if Authentication is required to get the Name property)

Comment: This resolves the error given, it isn't necessarily totally correct.

Comment: It's ok @StingyJack, but it gives me Error 1

Comment: Depending on how sensitive you set the compiler, some warnings may get treated as errors.  I have updated the code in my answer which has a fix though there is a possible null reference exception possible if the user isn't authenticated to handle here.